# Win 2003 Terminal Server, Logoff Domain Users after 30 mins

Tags: windows-server-2003

We have a terminal server in our environment, where Domain\Domain Users can login through Remote Desktop. We want to force log off these users after half an hour. However Administrators (this includes Domain\Domain Admin also) should not be affected by this. They should be able to connect to terminal server with out any interruption.

Can somebody guide us about it.

Thanks upfront

Kabir

Comment: Just checking - do you really want to force the log-off even during an active session or did you mean after 30 minutes of inactivity?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Siim K..i will check this and let you kknow..I need force log-off even during and active session for Domain Users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using [change local computer policy on windows 2003 terminal server](https://serverfault.com/questions/121065/change-local-computer-policy-on-windows-2003-terminal-server)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it through group policy:
User Configuration/Administrative templates/Windows Components/Terminal Services/Sessions

And [how to prevent it from applying to Administrators](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=816100)

Comment: I change the policy but it is getting applied to other user accounts also who are member of Administrator Group as well as another users. How ever the builtin user account Administrator remain unaffected. Please help..

Comment: I want to apply these settings for only one server in our domain..for all other server things would remain same.. None of the soulutins given here will fullfill my requirement.. Does logon script provide the solution..a logon script that will run in that server only.