# change local computer policy on windows 2003 terminal server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

i want to change the local computer policy in a windows 2003 terminal server which is part of domain.

The policy i want to change is "Sets a time limit for active Terminal services session" to Enabled and Active Sessions limit to 5 minutes, so that all active session can be terminated after time limit.

However, I don't want to enforce it on "domain\Domain Admin" who are part of local group Administrators as well local admin users of the server. Mostly I would like to enforce this policy on Domain\domain users who are member of Remote Desktop Users of this terminal server.

can somebody please help .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminal server time outs are a per-machine setting.  There is no way you are going to be able to have a per-computer setting behave differently per user.

You can set per-user session limits via policy, but you cannot use a local policy.  You'll have to setup a policy on your domain place it in an OU with your terminal server, set up loop-back processing, and set the per-user session limits.  See (User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Terminal Services\Terminal Server\Session Time Limits)

Refs:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754272(WS.10).aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758177(WS.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks Zoerdache..it worked. I did a reboot of terminal server after applying the policy in separate OU in AD.